# Hadoop property "mapred.child.tmp" does not create the directory if it doesn't exist

Tags: hadoop, directory, tmp

Per the below link -

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Directory#Structure

I was expecting hadoop to create the directory whose absolute path is sent as a value to the "mapred.child.tmp" property:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.tmp</name>
    <value>/hadoop/mapred/local/tmp</value>
</property>
```

The other thing I notice is that we cannot set this property using symbol @taskid@ as below:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.tmp</name>
    <value>/hadoop/mapred/local/tmp/@taskid@</value>
</property>
```

It would be nice to have it interpolated with the value of taskid of the map/reduce task similar to "mapred.child.java.opts". Not sure if there is another way around this...?

Thanks for any help in this matter!

Comment: In version 0.20.2 this replacement is available only for `mapred.child.java.opts`. Have a look at `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner#run()` method and check whether `@taskid@` replacement for `mapred.child.tmp` does the job.

Comment: Yes, it appears that the method createChildTmpDir() doesn't take "@taskid@" into account. The same behaviour is seen even in the latest hadoop code! This would be pretty useful to have...especially if mappers/reducers are auto-generated (as with higher level languages like JAQL) and hence you have lesser control over the happenings below.